# Pass environment variables to cmake when building with gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

my workflow is the following:

1. Execute script which is defining a temporary environment
   variables(export FOO=bar/setx FOO=bar).
2. launch Gradle build via android studio or the command line(./gradlew
   assemble)
3. Native build with cmake invoked but failed to read the
       previously exported env vars(using $ENV{FOO}).

I know that the environment variables are per-process (and child processes) and Gradle probably invokes a new shell causing the missing vars.

What I've tried:

1. Adding all those vars to ~/.bashrc is currently not an option, it will solve the issue though.
2. Running the script(the one which sets the env vars) from a Gradle task before the build.
3. Using:

   ```
   task addEnvVar(type: Exec) {
       environment "FOO", "bar"
       commandLine "doit"
   }
   ```

   preBuild.dependsOn addEnvVar

Any suggestion how I may approach my situation? Thanks!

Comment: how about `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file?

Comment: Eventually, my cmake file is trying to get an env var using $ENV{FOO} and I cant change this operation. Is there a way to define env vars in gradle so cmake will see those as env vars? I couldn't find a way.